# Documentation for CMX ColdFire USB-Lite stack

Tags: c, embedded, usb, coldfire

This is my first embedded project, so bear with my ignorance. I've been asked to implement Remote NDIS over USB, using the  **ColdFire USB-Lite** stack by CMX. I've been searching for a long time now, and can't find any clear documentation for this stack.

It comes with some woefully documented sample code and the only useful resource I've been able to find online is this [Application Note (PDF)](http://www.emgware.com/files/pub/AppNotes/an3492.pdf) by Eric Gregori.

What I really want is an explanation of all the functions in the API. I can work out how to use them. Does this exist? Can someone point me to it?

EDIT: Nevermind.

After tracing the execution across 14 half-documented source files (from the example program) and scrutinizing a bunch of undocumented variables and buffers, and doing a diff between corresponding files in different projects, I think I finally get it. So I guess stackoverflow.com taught me patience... or something.

Answer (score 0):

The link you referred to doesn't work for me, but the name of the file made me look at the [Freescale pages](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN3492.pdf), and if that's not the document you intended to link to, it might be the documentation you need.